# How can I prevent from getting source code from my apk

Tags: android

I know that there is a way to get some kind of source code from an android apk.
(according to [Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file))
How can I prevent other people from getting source code from my apk? Is it possible?

Thanks alot,
Keren :-)

Answer (score 6):

Enable `ProGuard` for your application. `ant` will call `ProGuard` to obfuscate your code. More details are here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can do obfuscation  for you app
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#FAQ.html